# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sc' Pyspark PMML

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, pmml

first time posting here! I am trying to save my Logistic Regression model via pyspark2pmml. However I keep getting the error stated in the title. I will post my pipeline and model code.

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import Binarizer

binarizer = Binarizer(threshold=10000, inputCol="traffic_count", outputCol="label")
stages = []
stages = [binarizer]


from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer, OneHotEncoder, VectorAssembler


SI_roadname = StringIndexer(inputCol='road_name',outputCol='road_Index')
SI_suburb = StringIndexer(inputCol='suburb',outputCol='suburb_Index')
SI_cardinal = StringIndexer(inputCol='cardinal_direction_name',outputCol='cardinal_Index')
SI_period = StringIndexer(inputCol='period',outputCol='period_Index')
SI_label = StringIndexer(inputCol='label',outputCol='label_index')

stages = []
stages += [SI_roadname, SI_suburb, SI_cardinal, SI_period, SI_label]

OHE = OneHotEncoder(inputCols['road_Index','suburb_Index','cardinal_Index','period_Index','label_index'],outputCols=['road_OHE','suburb_OHE','cardinal_OHE','period_OHE','label_OHE'])
stages += [OHE]


assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=['wgs84_latitude','wgs84_longitude'],outputCol='features')
stages += [assembler]

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=stages)
pipelineModel = pipeline.fit(df)
model = pipelineModel.transform(df)

from pyspark.ml.linalg import DenseVector
input_data = model.rdd.map(lambda x: (x["label"], DenseVector(x["features"])))
df_train = sqlContext.createDataFrame(input_data, ["label", "features"])


train, test = df_train.randomSplit([0.7,0.3])

lr = LogisticRegression(labelCol='label')
lr_model = lr.fit(train)


pred_labels = lr_model.evaluate(test)
pred_labels.predictions.show()
```

So the particular error I got comes from this line

```
from pyspark2pmml import PMMLBuilder

PMMLBuilder(spark, df, pipelineModel)
PMMLBuilder.buildFile("lr_model.pmml","path")
```

I am very new to using using Pyspark in general so I hope someone can give me a helping hand. I will post some screen shots too for context.

[The Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYj3J.png)

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pe2ph.png)

[model.take(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9fss.png)

[Predictions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6gQb.png)

Comment: I have tried googling the error, but none of the results fit specifically to this context.

Comment: Hello @Tardigrade, I got same error with your case. What is `spark` variable and how you define it when you build a pmml file `PMMLBuilder(spark, df, pipelineModel)` ? is that sparkContext or sparkSession? Thank you.

Comment: @furanzup hello, it's been quite a while since I last worked on it, but I believe it is sparkSession if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting **self** argument of the object with the string "lr_model.pmml". That's why you're receiving the error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sc' Pyspark PMML`.
You have to call buildFile passing a path as argument, [see](https://github.com/jpmml/pyspark2pmml/blob/744cce4c1a36c4e7cfb9be703d7518fcf161b0e9/pyspark2pmml/__init__.py#L25).

```py
    def buildFile(self, path):
        javaFile = self.sc._jvm.java.io.File(path)
        javaFile = self.javaPmmlBuilder.buildFile(javaFile)
        return javaFile.getAbsolutePath()
```

From the README of the library:

```py
from pyspark2pmml import PMMLBuilder

pmmlBuilder = PMMLBuilder(sc, df, pipelineModel)

pmmlBuilder.buildFile("DecisionTreeIris.pmml")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I understood what you meant so I formatted it a little differently. I wrote "PMMLBuilder(spark, df, pipelineModel).buildFile("lr_model.pmml")" and it worked! Cheers!